# Conditional loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I am following courses in FreeCodeCamp to learn Javascript. I am in "Diff in Two Arrays". Assignment is comparing two arrays and return a new array with any items only found in one of the two given arrays, but not both.

Below is the code I try to compare them, second part does not apply. I want to undertand why second part of the conditional loop does not work.

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var filtered = [];
  var l = 0;
  newArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  for (var j=0; j < newArr.length; j++){
    for (var k=0; k < newArr[j].length; k++){
       //values to check before and next index 
       l  = j + 1;
       var m = j-1;
       if (l < newArr.length){
            if (newArr[l].indexOf(newArr[j][k]) === -1){
                filtered.push(newArr[j][k]);
            } else if (j == newArr.length - 1){ // this part does not work
                console.log(j);
                if (newArr[m].indexOf(newArr[j][k]) === -1 ){
                    console.log(newArr[j]);
                    filtered.push(newArr[l][k]);
                }
            }        
         }
       }
    }
  // Same, same; but different.
  return filtered;
}

diffArray([1, "calf", 3, "piglet"], [1, "calf", 3, 4]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: because in your example it never was true

Comment: `newArr.length` will be 2 
so in first loop `j==0` when the interpreter reaches to your condition 
`j == newArr.length - 1`  `newArr.length - 1 = 1` and `j=0` 
` 0 !== 1`  
then in second loop where `j==1`  first 2 loops of `k` the first condition will be true

Comment: When `j` is 0, you don't get through condition `else if (j == newArr.length - 1)`, where j=0, newArr.length =2.

When `j` is 1, you don't get through condition `if (l < newArr.length){` because of `l  = j + 1;`, where j=1, so `if(2<2)` will be false.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way :

```
var arr1 = [1,2,34,5,6,7,8,9];
var arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var diff = arr1.concat(arr2).sort().filter((x, index, arr) => (x != arr[index+1] && x != arr[index-1]));
console.log(diff); // [ 3, 34, 4 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to solve this problem,hope it can help you.
first I loop arr1,and see can it found some match in arr2 and push it in newArr
second I do the same thing as first step,but reverse arr1 and arr2,and push it newArr.

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = [];

  for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
      if(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i])<0){
        newArr.push(arr1[i]);
      }
  }
  for(var j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
    if(arr1.indexOf(arr2[j])<0){
      newArr.push(arr2[j]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
console.log(diff); // [ 3, 34, 4 ]

diff([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```